# SetWindowLongPtr not seem to work

Tags: c, winapi, subclass, setwindowlong

*I tried to subclass another window (in another process) so I injected a dll, which calls SetWindowLongPtr, but it fails and GetLastError returns 5.*

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain (HANDLE hDll, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (dwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            HWND hwnd = GetHwndProc();

            if (!(orgWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)SubclassProc)))
            {
                char buf[40];
                sprintf(buf, "Error code: %d", GetLastError());
                MessageBox(hwnd, buf, "Error", MB_OK);
            }   
            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

EDIT: Its defiantly the right PID.

EDIT 2: **I was getting the wrong HWND** but that is fixed now (edited the code as well) 
**I'm no longer getting the error 5 (from GetLastError)**

```
    HWND GetHwndProc()
{
    HWND hwnd = GetTopWindow(NULL);
    DWORD currentPID = GetCurrentProcessId();
    do
    {
        char title[256];
        if ((GetWindowText(hwnd, title, 256) > 0) && (IsWindowVisible(hwnd)))
        {
            DWORD procId;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procId);

            if (procId == currentPID)   
            {
                MessageBox(hwnd, title, "", MB_OK);
                return hwnd;
            }
        }

        hwnd = GetNextWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT);
    } while (hwnd);
}

WNDPROC orgWndProc;
LRESULT APIENTRY SubclassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            MessageBox(0, "Subclass", "", 0);
            return TRUE;

        default:
            return CallWindowProc(orgWndProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Sounds to me you are just injecting the wrong process.  Make sure it isn't your own.  Display the value of GetCurrentProcessId() to verify.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes its the right PID, maybe its not the right hwnd then? (its the hwnd with the title, so I thought that should be the WndProc. I'll post my GetHwndProc())

Comment: You can most certainly call SetWindowSubclass from mingw.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what should I link? I included Commctrl.h and linked with Commctl32 but still no success.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `SetWindowSubclass` from the thread where the window was created, at which the message queue associated with it runs. From `SetWindowSubclass` [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **Warning**  You cannot use the subclassing helper functions to subclass a window across threads.

In turn `SetWindowLongPtr` must be called from the process where the window was created. From `SetWindowLongPtr` [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> **Windows XP/2000**:   The `SetWindowLongPtr` function fails if the window specified by the hWnd parameter does not belong to the same process as the calling thread.

There is also the *User Interface Privilege Isolation* which restricts access even further.

Comment: Ah well, thank you but its not really helpful as mingw doesn't include/support that function: Undefined reference to SetWindowSubclass (also for DefSubclassProc)

Comment: SetWindowSubclass can't work across threads because it maintains a per-thread chain of subclasses internally, but sub-classing using SetWindowLongPtr should work. I suggest you try the steps Hans suggested above.